# How do I split 1 column of data based on the value in a 2nd column in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my database that looks like this; L for Loaded and E for Empty:

[image: Loaded/Empty]

with a column in the same table with Mileage:

[image: Mileage]

I'm trying to find a way to have it separate and sum() up totals for all Mileage that's Loaded and Empty into 2 columns that would say Total Loaded Mileage and Total Empty Mileage?

Something like this: 
[image: Total]

I've tried a case, self join, and possibly a pivot or view and I can't figure out how to get what I want.

Comment: You might want to show us what you've tried. Also sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an IF ([actually IIF in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)):

```
COALESCE(SUM(IF(loaded = 'L', move_distance, 0)),0) AS when_loaded,
COALESCE(SUM(IF(loaded = 'E', move_distance, 0)),0) AS when_empty
```

The `COALESCE` allows for the pathologic case when the table is empty (or any additional WHERE yields no matches), and the SUM would return NULL.

Or `CASE`:

```
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN loaded = 'L' THEN move_distance ELSE 0 END), 0)
```

Comment: I did see something about using a Coalesce. Let me fiddle with that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Not sure if syntax will allow those IF's

Comment: And right you are. Added the appropriate function for SQL Server, and a workaround.

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for. Let me double check the totals I'm getting against the database.

Comment: As far as I can tell this works. The numbers are very close and it maybe that the snapshot of the data i'm looking at vs the live data is throwing numbers off slightly. Will take some time to see if this works correctly, but as far as I can tell it looks like the solution I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest in my experience is create this query as a union:

```
Select Loaded, move_distance Move_Loaded, 0 Move_Empty
from mytable
where Loaded = 'L'
UNION
Select Loaded, 0 , move_distance
from mytable
where Loaded = 'E'
```

If you want just the sums use:

```
Select Loaded, sum(move_distance) Move_Loaded, 0 Move_Empty
from mytable
where Loaded = 'L'
group by Loaded, 0
UNION
Select Loaded, 0 , sum(move_distance)
from mytable
where Loaded = 'E'
group by Loaded, 0
```

You might be able to leave out the "0" from your group by lines.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way with normal sql is as below.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN loaded = 'L' THEN move_distance ELSE 0 END) as 
LoadedMoveDistance
SUM(CASE WHEN loaded = 'E' THEN move_distance ELSE 0 END) as 
LoadedMoveDistance
FROM tablename
```

other way is to use Pivot which is SQL server specific it will something as below.

```
select [L] as Move_distance_loaded, [E] as Move_distance_empty
from
(
Select loaded, move_distance from table
) tb
PIVOT
(
SUM(move_distance)
FOR loaded IN ([L], [E])
) As pvt
```

you need to try pivot thing, above code will not work as exactly provided.